# Compile with no optimization in clang

Tags: clang

**Short question:** how to compile with `clang` with no code optimization? `-O0` is not working.

**Long question:**
I'm learning code optimization and LLVM in particular. I'm writing small examples, compiling them and then running just one optimization at a time, to analyze what it changes. For example, to test Dead Code Elimination, I tried this:

```
int main() {
    int a = 20 + 30;
    int b = 25; /* Assignment to dead variable */
    int c;
    c = a << 2;
    return c;
    b = 24; /* Unreachable code */
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile it with

```
clang -S -O0 -emit-llvm foo.c
```

The last two lines of my C code do not show up in the IR code (below). Also, the `20 + 30` is already being calculated to 50. So there's some optimization going on here, even though I'm using `-O0`.

```
; ModuleID = 'hello.c'
target datalayout = "e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-s0:64:64-f80:128:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  %c = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval
  store i32 50, i32* %a, align 4
  store i32 25, i32* %b, align 4
  %0 = load i32* %a, align 4
  %shl = shl i32 %0, 2
  store i32 %shl, i32* %c, align 4
  %1 = load i32* %c, align 4
  ret i32 %1
}

attributes #0 = { nounwind uwtable "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.ident = !{!0}

!0 = metadata !{metadata !"clang version 3.4 (trunk 192936)"}
```

Comment: Those types of super simple optimizations are probably done long before the 'optimization' phase, perhaps as early as the lexing phase. That would make it almost impossible to stop without modifying clang itself.

Comment: I wouldn't call dead code removal optimization.
Why should the support this? I cannot think of any use case.

Comment: There's at least one use case: while learning to exploit binaries (like buffer overflows), trying to write C code that does exactly match the instructions of the binary.